# Minikube - invalid option "-p"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Getting the following error on executing the following command . Please let me know how to fix this

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep kube-proxy                          
netstat: invalid option -- 'p'                                   
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2020-03-26 11:18:09 PDT) multi-call binary.     

Usage: netstat [-ral] [-tuwx] [-en]
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/219984/busybox-netstat-no-p

Comment: it doesnt seem it is straightforward using this in minikube